# @fontface: font is found, but not displayed

Tags: css

My problem with @fontface is stumping me.  What I've got right now is:

```
    @font-face
    {
    font-family: 'FranklinGothic';
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/theme/FranklinGothicDemiCondensed.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

and I link it in the css with

```
    body, input, textarea
    {
        color: #222;    
        font-family: 'FranklinGothic', MrAlex, Arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

I've tried it with and without the quote marks around the name/urls.  I've also successfully added the custom font MrAlex which is in the same location (so I'm pretty confident the class path is right).  The other thing that makes me think my path is right is that there is no 404 error in the developer console.  Additionally, the Franklin Gothic font is listed in resources under fonts in the developer tools.
I'm just trying to get this working in chrome at the moment.  Any ideas?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this happening in one specific browser or all of them?

Comment: Actually, it is working on Safari...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the fallbacks, and setting the font-family to only 'FranklinGothic'. Try in incognito mode. Try a different font hosted somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for answering, removing the fallbacks didn't help, neither did incognito.  Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time finding this particular font somewhere else - although, it is a .ttf file, so isn't it hosted on my server along with the rest of my code?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. I suggested trying a different font in case something was wrong with your particular font, or the file format wasn't correct.